# Logging into my WebMatrix razor C# site as a newly registered user is throwing errors

Tags: c#, database, razor, authentication, webmatrix

I am having a problem I can't seem to track down.  I am not able to logon after registering through my WebMatrix site.  Before the registration was set up to send a confirmation token in email, I was able to log in just fine. Here is the YSOD error I am getting (The error occurs specifically on line 21 of the login file):

```
Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type 'WebMatrix.Data.DynamicRecord' to 'string'

Source Error: 


Line 19:             {
Line 20:                 var db = Database.Open("Users");
Line 21:                 user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT firstName FROM UserProfile WHERE  LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", username);
Line 22: 
Line 23:                 AppState["gActionMessage"] = "Hello, " + user + "!";

Source File: c:\Users\cradebaugh\Documents\My Web Sites\Persons Of Interest\Account\Login.cshtml    Line: 21
```

And here are the concerning files:

**REGISTER PAGE:**

```
@{
var email = "";
var firstName = "";
var lastName = "";
var password = "";
var confirmPassword ="";
var errorMessage = "";
AppState["gActionMessage"] = "";
if(IsPost)
{
    email = Request.Form["email"];
    firstName = Request.Form["firstName"];
    lastName = Request.Form["lastName"];
    password = Request.Form["password"];
    confirmPassword = Request.Form["confirmPassword"];

    if(email.IsEmpty() || password.IsEmpty())
    {
        errorMessage = "You must specify both an email address and a password";
    }

    if(password != confirmPassword)
    {
        errorMessage = "The password and the confirmation password do not match.";
    }

    if(!EmailValidator.IsEmailAdress(email))
    {
        errorMessage = "The email you entered is not a valid email address.";
    }

    if(firstName=="" || lastName=="")
    {
        errorMessage = "You must provide both a first and last name";
    }

    if(errorMessage=="")
    {
        var db = Database.Open("Users");
        var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);
        if(user==null)
        {
            WebSecurity.Logout();
            db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email, IPAddress, firstName, lastName) VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)", email, Request.UserHostAddress, firstName, lastName);

            var token = WebSecurity.CreateAccount(email, password, true);
            var hostUrl = Request.Url.GetComponents(UriComponents.SchemeAndServer, UriFormat.Unescaped);
            var confirmationUrl = hostUrl + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Account/Confirm?confirmationCode=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token) + "&firstName=" + firstName);

            WebMail.Send(
                    to: email,
                    subject: "Please confirm your account",
                    body: "Your confirmation code is: " + token + ". Visit <a href=\"" + confirmationUrl + "\">" + confirmationUrl + "</a> to activate your account."
                    );

            AppState["gActionMessage"] = "An email to confirm your account has been emailed to you.";
            AppState["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
            Response.Redirect("~/IntroPage.cshtml");


        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "That email address is already in use.";
        }
    }
}
}

@RenderPage("~/Shared/HeaderLayout.cshtml")
        <div style="color: #808080;">
            <span class="heading">Register</span>
            <span style="font-size: 3em;">________________________________________________</span></br></br></br>
        </div>
        @{
            if (errorMessage != "")
            {
                <div class="errorMessageWrapper">@errorMessage</div><br/>
            }
        }
        <div class="accInterfaceWrapper">
            <form class="accInterfaceForm" method="post" action="">
                <table class="accInterfaceTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                            <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="accInterfaceInputCell">
                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="@email" /><br/><br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                            <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="accInterfaceInputCell">
                            <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value="@firstName" /><br/><br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                            <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="accInterfaceInputCell">
                            <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value="@lastName" /><br/><br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                            <label for="password">Create Password:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br/><br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                            <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm Password:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" /><br/><br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br/><br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="location.href='/IntroPage.cshtml'">Main Page</button><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Register" />
            </form>
        </div>
@RenderPage("~/Shared/FooterLayout.cshtml")
```

Here is the **Confirmation Page**:

```
@{

var errorMessage = "";
var confirmationToken = Request["confirmationCode"];
var firstName = Request["firstName"];

WebSecurity.Logout();
if (!confirmationToken.IsEmpty())
{
    if(WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(confirmationToken))
    {
        AppState["gActionMessage"] = "Welcome to the POI Database, "  + firstName + "!";
        AppState["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
        Response.Redirect("~/");
    }
    else
    {
        errorMessage = "An error occurred while trying to confirm your account. " +
                       "Please try again.";
    }
}
}
@RenderPage("~/Shared/HeaderLayout.cshtml")
        <div style="color: #808080;">
            <span class="heading">Confirm Account</span>
            <span style="font-size: 3em;">________________________________________________</span></br></br></br>
        </div>
            @if (errorMessage != "")
            {
                <div class="errorMessageWrapper">@errorMessage</div><br/>
            }
@RenderPage("~/Shared/FooterLayout.cshtml")
```

And, finally, the **Login Page:**

```
@{
var username = "";
var user = "";
var password = "";
var errorMessage = "";
AppState["gActionMessage"] = "";
if(IsPost)
{
    username = Request.Form["username"];
    password = Request.Form["password"];

    if(username.IsEmpty() || password.IsEmpty())
    {
        errorMessage = "You must specify both a username and password.";
    }
    else
    {
        if(WebSecurity.Login(username, password, false))
        {
            var db = Database.Open("Users");
            user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT firstName FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", username);

            AppState["gActionMessage"] = "Hello, " + user + "!";
            AppState["gActionMessageDisplayed"] = "not";
            Response.Redirect("~/");
        }
        else
        {
            errorMessage = "Login failed";
        }
    }
}

}


@RenderPage("~/Shared/HeaderLayout.cshtml")
        <div style="color: #808080;">
            <span class="heading">Please Log In</span>
            <span style="font-size: 3em;">________________________________________________</span></br></br></br>
        </div>
        @{
            if (errorMessage != "")
            {
                <div class="errorMessageWrapper">@errorMessage</div><br/>
            }
        }
        <div class="accInterfaceWrapper">
            <form class="accInterfaceForm" method="post" action="">
                <table class="accInterfaceTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                            <label for="username">Email Address:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td class="accInterfaceInputCell">
                            <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="@username" /><br/><br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="accInterfaceLabelCell">
                            <label for="password">Password:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" /><br/><br/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><br/><br/>
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="location.href='/IntroPage.cshtml'">Main Page</button><input class="btn" type="submit" value="Log In" />
            </form>
            <a href="~/Account/Register.cshtml">Don't have a Account?</a><br/><br/>
            <a href="~/Account/ForgotPassword.cshtml">Forgot your password?</a>
        </div>
@RenderPage("~/Shared/FooterLayout.cshtml")
```

Again, the error actually gets thrown when I try to login, and confirmation is set to true in the database, so I know they get successfully registered, but without changing a thing in the login file, it began erroring only after changing the registration/confirmation files.

Sorry to hit you with so much code, but the problem could be anywhere among these three pages.  Just let me know if anyone needs more info, or other files, and I will respond immediately.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you able to debug the code? Is the `username` variable set to a string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on the login screen.  The variable user is defined as a string.  db.QuerySingle is returning a row, which is a dynamic object.  This is true even though you are selecting just one field.  You could do the following

```
var rowResults = db.QuerySingle( "...");
user = rowResults.firstName;
```

Or you could change the line to return a single value.

```
user = db.QueryValue( "Select firstName...");
```

Comment: Wow, I returned to this question after trying a few things and I got this to work also

user = (db.QuerySingle("...")).firstName;

Which is essentially everything you are talking about.  THANK YOU, SO MUCH for helping me clear up how the information gathered from a simple query is handled.  This will help me so much now and in the future.

Really, thank you and GREAT answer!

Comment: I never realized I could use QueryValue, but what would the value be if it found multiple entries, or even worse, multiple entries of different data types? Just curious

Comment: I think QueryValue would throw an exception if you got back multiple rows or more than one field.  Or an exception if the type didn't match.